# How to prevent ModalBottomSheet from overlapping in system buttons

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3

[What it is currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7Zl8.png)
The bottom sheet container overlaps with the three buttons. how do i make it go in the screen instead of in the system ui?
My code

```
val sheetState = rememberModalBottomSheetState()
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    var showBottomSheet by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    Scaffold(
        floatingActionButton = {
            ExtendedFloatingActionButton(
                text = { Text("Show bottom sheet") },
                icon = { Icon(Icons.Filled.Add, contentDescription = "") },
                onClick = {
                    showBottomSheet = true
                }
            )
        }
    ) { contentPadding ->
        // Screen content

        if (showBottomSheet) {
            ModalBottomSheet(
                onDismissRequest = {
                    showBottomSheet = false
                },
                sheetState = sheetState
            ) {
                // Sheet content
                Button(onClick = {
                    scope.launch { sheetState.hide() }.invokeOnCompletion {
                        if (!sheetState.isVisible) {
                            showBottomSheet = false
                        }
                    }
                }) {
                    Text("Hide bottom sheet")
                }
            }
        }
}
```

[What i want it to look like (Docs)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSzEH.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welp, guess I found a temporary fix.

```
ModalBottomSheet(
            onDismissRequest = {
                showBottomSheet = false
            },
            sheetState = sheetState,
            windowInsets = WindowInsets(0),
        ) {
            // Sheet content
            Button(onClick = {
                scope.launch { sheetState.hide() }.invokeOnCompletion {
                    if (!sheetState.isVisible) {
                        showBottomSheet = false
                    }
                }
            }) {
                Text("Hide bottom sheet")

            }
            Spacer(
                Modifier.navigationBarsPadding()) // add spacer with navigationBarsPadding
        }
```

[Doesn't overlap now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Ub48.png).

I hope that the compose team makes this more intuitive in the stable release of material3 1.2.0 .

Comment: Works great thanks! Didn't know about the navigationBarsPadding modifier :)